# backbonejs with underscorejs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I used backbone js and append function to display the output of a value this is my old working code (in short). The below code is just to keep you posted that the code is working.

```
this.$el.append('<li class="linkbackbreadcrumbs">'+model.get('sourceName')+'</li>');}
```

---

Now i need to use underscore js to pass the data to template and need to populate data over there.

**From View**

```
Backbone.View.extend({
                    el: $('#secondBoxList'),
                    initialize: function(){
                        this.render();
                    },
                    template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),
                    render: function(eventName) {
                         this.$el.html(this.template({who: this.collection.toJSON()}));
                      }
        });
```

**For Testing Purpose**
This works fine.

```
        <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
          <h3>Hello <%= who %></h3>
         </script>
```

**Output**
 Hello [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I want it to display the sourceName and also check if the sourceName exists i should skip. Sample json is below.

```
[
    {
    "sourceName": "Apple"

    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Windows"
    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Ubunut"

    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Linux Mint"
    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Fedora"

    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Windows"
    },
    {
    "sourceName": "Dummy"

    }
]
```

I tried each function but i am getting values not defined. Uncaught ReferenceError: values is not defined

How can i get my sourceName populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in the template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <% _.each(who,function(item))      
    <h3>Hello <%= item.sourceName %></h3>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/template" id="item-template">

                              <% for(var name in who) { %>
                                       <li><%= who[name].sourceName %></li>
                                   <% } %>

                    </script>
```

This provides the desired output.